# jquery UI tab design doesnt wrk well

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to use the jquery UI tab feature from  the link http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/manipulation.html

What I did is copied the source code from the webpage to an html file in my pc.. Also added corresponding css and js files and linked them index page. bt there seems to be a problem with the css part as the design is not wrking fine in my page. The issue seems to be with the file jquery.ui.all.css

whose content is

```
/*!
* jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.8.21
*
* Copyright 2012, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming
*/
 @import "jquery.ui.base.css";
 @import "jquery.ui.theme.css";
```

Nw my page looks like the screenshot ive attached ... the list styling doesnt seem to be wrking....[image]

How does the `@import` thing wrk??Could that be the issue?

Comment: I take it you have got a local copy of those two css files? The `@import` is loading up those two css files and if you do not have a copy, then that is why there are no stylings

Comment: I dont have the copy of those files locally...

Comment: but the website is nt providing copy of those two files..

Comment: Can you post the code of the page where you are using the tabs. Better if you do it with http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you inspect the styling on the website, it will show you the imported css files. You might want to just download a jQuery UI theme though because this will download the main CSS file, and you don't need to worry about all the `@imports`

Comment: I will tell u what Ive done.. I rightclicked on page  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/manipulation.html and took the option view source code and copied the main html file contents and all the file contents attached to the main file and added them to different files and linked all of them to main index..

Comment: @TimBJames Thanks for that....if you could type in as a separate answer, I would mark it as correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet which is being used uses `@imports` to import 2 other stylesheets. From within one of these stylesheets that is being imported, it is then importing more stylesheets. So you will need all of these for this demo to work.

I would suggest downloading one of the themes from jQueryUI as these dont use `@imports` and have all the styles.

Alternatively, use a CDN to access the javascript and css files. I use the [Microsoft CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_UI_Releases_on_the_CDN_1)
You can add a link in your project to:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing following css file in your html.

http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css

@import is used to link css file in your HTML file